# Display and read an Excel file into a datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I have successfully displayed the data using a code I found at this particular website. The problem is, the colour, bold or italics of the font isn't carried over. I need to read the code of a specific cell and convert it into a HTML string and display it as a textbox elsewhere. So I really need to learn how to import colour, bold or italics so I can convert it too. I will be eternally grateful to any kind soul who helps me on this one. Below is my current code.

```
string PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [sheet1$]", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Visual formatting is specific to the Excel application, querying it via anything thats not designed specifically to be used with Excel, like SQL, will only ever return textual data.  You would need to use Office automation to open the excel file, loop the cells your interested in, parse out their formatting values and translate them into whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

The following opens an Excel file in the app folder, get cell value, fore color, see if bold and italic is set for range sheet1 cell H2. Please note there is a decent amount of code which is warranted so that all objects used here are released upon finishing our work.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1_CS
{
    public class ExcelCode
    {
        public System.Drawing.Color ForeColor;
        public ExcelCode() { }

        public string GetCellValue(
            string FileName,
            string SheetName,
            string CellAddress)
        {
            string CellValue = "";

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(FileName))
            {
                bool Proceed = false;

                Excel.Application xlApp = null;
                Excel.Workbooks xlWorkBooks = null;
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
                Excel.Sheets xlWorkSheets = null;
                Excel.Range xlCells = null;

                xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
                xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(FileName);

                xlApp.Visible = false;

                xlWorkSheets = xlWorkBook.Sheets;

                for (int x = 1; x <= xlWorkSheets.Count; x++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkSheets[x];

                    if (xlWorkSheet.Name == SheetName)
                    {
                        Proceed = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    System.Runtime.InteropServices
                        .Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);

                    xlWorkSheet = null;

                }

                if (Proceed)
                {
                    xlCells = xlWorkSheet.Range[CellAddress];

                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Bold: {0}", xlCells.Font.Bold);   //  bool
                        Console.WriteLine("Italic: {0}", xlCells.Font.Italic); // bool
                        ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle((int)xlCells.Font.Color);
                        CellValue = Convert.ToString(xlCells.Value);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // Reduntant
                        CellValue = "";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(SheetName + " not found.");
                }

                xlWorkBook.Close();
                xlApp.UserControl = true;
                xlApp.Quit();

                ReleaseComObject(xlCells);
                ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheets);
                ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
                ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
                ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBooks);
                ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("'" + FileName +
                    "' not located. Try one of the write examples first.");
            }

            return CellValue;
        }

        public static void ReleaseComObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                    obj = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                obj = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form code which works from a button and has a panel
            var demoExcel = new ExcelCode();
            // open an Excel file in the app folder, get information from H2 in Sheet1
            textBox1.Text = demoExcel
                .GetCellValue(
                Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Demo.xlsx"), 
                "Sheet1", 
                "H2");

```
        // Form has a panel, set back color to Sheet1.H2 color
        panel1.BackColor = demoExcel.ForeColor;
        // Translate the color to HTML
        var htmlColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(demoExcel.ForeColor);
        Console.WriteLine(htmlColor.ToString());
```